# what is the best way to seperate dynamic and static enums in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have two types of enum .Some come from the server and others are statically defined in code.

My question is what is the best way to determine if an **Enum** is static or dynamic?

1-search on a List of static enums.

2-use object oriented methods.

Comment: How are you generating dynamics enums?

Comment: just send a get request to the server

Comment: get request will give you the data how are you generating the enum afterwards in typescript?

Comment: i dont need to generate enum actually .i just use that return data as items of ngselect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

enum built using typescript or "static enum" are plain objects so to differentiate them from "dynamic enums"(plain objects), you can create a class for dynamic enum and create an instance of it and assign the api data to this newly created instance to later check on runtime whether it's a static or dynamic enum like this:

```js
class DynamicEnum {}

enum Status {
    Ok,
    Error
}

const apiData = JSON.parse(`{ "Ok": 0, "Error": 1 }`);
const enumBuiltUsingApiData = Object.assign(new DynamicEnum(), apiData);


const isEnumStaticOrDynamic = (e: any) => {
    console.log(e instanceof DynamicEnum ? "dynamic enum" : "static enum");
}

isEnumStaticOrDynamic(Status); // output: "static enum"
isEnumStaticOrDynamic(enumBuiltUsingApiData); // output: "dynamic enum"
```

Comment: thank you very much.this is a good idea.i used something like this